# HTML form failed to validate using the jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm aware that this is likely poorly formatted and/or coded.  I'm looking for an answer as to why it doesn't give a message that the first name field is required.  The submit button at the moment isn't working at all, no values are being printed to the screen.  When just doing a form scrape it was working.  Could anyone tell me why the validation for the one form isn't working?  I made sure my jQuery validation plugin is hooked in.  Bits of my html and JS code are below.  This is for a school project.

```
<form id = "form">
<div> 
<label for = "firstName">First Name</label>
<input type = "text" id = "firstName" placeholder = "Type First Name Here" 
name = "firstName" required autofocus >
<br><br>
<label for = "lastName">Last Name</label>
<input type = "text" id = "lastName" name = "lastName">
</div>
<br>
<div>
<label for = "phone">Phone Number</label>
<input type = "tel" id = "phone">
</div>

<br>

<div> <p>
<label>Email</label>
<input type = "email" id = "email">

Password 
<input type = "password" id = "pass">
</p>
</div>

<br>
<div> Which level of skill do you believe fits you (or your child) best? 
</div>
Beginner<input type = "radio" value = "Beginner" name = "level">
Intermediate<input type = "radio" value = "Intermediate" name = "level">
Advanced<input type = "radio" value = "Advanced" name = "level"> 
<div id = "level"></div>
<br>
<br>

<label for = "age-spinner">Student Age</label>
<input id = "age-spinner" value = "5">

<br>
<br>
<div>Which days are you most available for a weekly piano lesson?</div>

<input type = "checkbox" value = "Monday" id = "monday" name = "days">Monday
<input type = "checkbox" value = "Tuesday" id = "tuesday" name = 
"days">Tuesday
<input type = "checkbox" value = "Wednesday" id = "wednesday" name = 
"days">Wednesday
<input type = "checkbox" value = "Thursday" id = "thursday" name = 
"days">Thursday
<input type = "checkbox" value = "Friday" id = "friday" name = "days">Friday
<input type = "checkbox" value = "Saturday" id = "saturday" name = 
"days">Saturday
<br>
<br>
<div>Best starting date? </div>
<input type = "text" id = "startDate">
</form>
<br><br>

<input type = "submit" id = "submit"> 
<button type= "button" id = "reset">Reset</button>
```

^^HTML Code.  JS Code below.  These are held in separate files.

```
$( "input[type='submit']" ).button();

$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(){


    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName =$("#lastName").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    var age = $("#age-spinner").val();
    var level = $("input[name='level']:checked").val();
    var startDate = $("#startDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd,MM,yyyy' }).val();
    var days = " ";

//function to fill in data inputted from days
$("input[name='days']:checked").each(function(){
    days += $(this).val() + ", "
});

$("#output").append("<br><br>Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName)
            .append("<br>Phone #: " + phone)
            .append("<br>Email: " + email)
            .append("<br>Password: " + pass)
            .append("<br>Student Age: " + age)
            .append("<br>Student Level: " + level)
            .append("<br>Proposed Start Date: " + startDate)
            .append("<br>Available Days: " + days);

alert("Passed validation and submitted.");
}//end submitHandler
});

$("#form").validate();
```

Comment: Those are just snippets.  I've never asked a question on here, if anything else is needed please let me know.

Comment: `I'm aware that this is likely poorly formatted and/or coded`. Please take the time to format your code when asking questions, its important for people to easily understand what you are trying to do, and formatting and indenting is key there. I would suggest using a code snipped instead?

Comment: the submit button should be in the form. you left it out.